# В операции должен использоваться обновляемый подзапрос

Tags: access, mysql, sql

В Access 2013 пытаюсь создать запрос для заполнения поля СР_балл:

```sql
UPDATE Студент t1 SET t1.СР_балл = (SELECT AVG(Оценка) 
FROM Успеваемость t2 WHERE t2.ИН_Студ = t1.ИН_Студ)
```

но всё время эта ошибка:

> В операции должен использоваться
>   обновляемый подзапрос

Comment: Студент - это таблица или сохраненный запрос (представление)?

Comment: Там все таблицы, есть запрос, называется 'Успеваемость Запрос'

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй вот так:

```sql
UPDATE Студент t1 SET t1.СР_балл = AVG(t2.Оценка) 
FROM Успеваемость t2 WHERE t2.ИН_Студ = t1.ИН_Студ
```

Comment: Ошибка синтаксиса(пропущен оператор) в выражении запроса 'AVG(t2.Оценка) FROM Успеваемость t2'

Comment: @Юра Сучко перед AVG() поставь SELECT, т.е. UPDATE Студент t1 SET t1.СР_балл = SELECT AVG(t2.Оценка) FROM....

Answer (score 1):

```sql
UPDATE Студент as t1 SET t1.СР_балл = (
    SELECT AVG(Оценка) FROM Успеваемость as t2 WHERE t2.ИН_Студ = t1.ИН_Студ
)
```